# javax.servlet.request.ssl_session_id is null in openshift

Tags: openshift, wildfly-8

Hi I am developing an application that I need to get the ssl id from a servlet. I am using Wildfly 8.2 and Openshift.

Currently to get the ssl id we only need to do this:

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.ssl_session_id");
```

and if I run in local wildfly it works perfectly, but when I deploy the application to openshift (free plan), although I access with https correctly (browser sets https connection as valid and as valid certificate), the previous call returns a null because the property javax.servlet.request.ssl_session_id is not set. I don't know if I am missing something or if this is not possible in openshift.

As I said in local it works perfectly.

Thank you so much.
Alex.

Comment: On OpenShift and on standard Production Deployments, TLS is typically offloaded to a proxy server. This is probably why request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.ssl_session_id") doesn't work. But why do you want o know the ssl session id?